# Why does Stripe API output "Request metrics buffer is full, dropping telemetry message."?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

In Node v12 with the Stripe API client v, I am running a `client.getSubscription()` call on about 200 items in a loop.

I get this message in the output (`--trace-warnings` is turned on):

```
Getting subscription data for a@email.com...
Getting subscription data for b@email.com...
Getting subscription data for c@email.com...
(node:25078) Stripe: Request metrics buffer is full, dropping telemetry message.
    at Object.emitWarning (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:437:18)
    at Constructor._recordRequestMetrics (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:370:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:192:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(node:25078) Stripe: Request metrics buffer is full, dropping telemetry message.
    at Object.emitWarning (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:437:18)
    at Constructor._recordRequestMetrics (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:370:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/nick/src/project/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:192:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(node:15748) Stripe: Request metrics buffer is full, dropping telemetry message.
...
```

I think this error is coming from an underlying library that Stripe is using, since I cannot find any information on Google or Stripe's docs with that specific error in it.

It also does not appear to be a critical error, the calls succeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a warning that's emitted from stripe-node when request telemetry can't be sent because the buffer is full: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/12ebce4220c22e1e1a6a0480ba96c2baffe01b8c/lib/StripeResource.js#L395

The telemetry is latency information which is sent to Stripe for [metrics purposes](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#request-latency-telemetry).

It's safe to ignore these as they are just warnings and won't affect the actual API operations. If however they are a bit too noisy for your liking you can disable telemetry entirely with the [config object](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#initialize-with-config-object):

```js
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_...', {
  telemetry: false,
});
```